# Alternatives in UWP for multibinding as in WPF?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

New to xaml. So i have a situation where i use a listview to populate a collection. A property of the data-template will need to bind to two or more properties of the collection item.

I saw few solutions of adding dependency property in my converters and binding them in the page resource and finally add it as part of another binding inside data-template. But i am not sure how to refer to a property of my collection item in the page resource!!

Any solution to this or some other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `MultiBindingBehavior` from [Cimbalino Toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Cimbalino.Toolkit/). It provides a similar functionality to `MultiBinding` in WPF:

```
<TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"
        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior PropertyName="Text" 
                Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}" 
                ConverterParameter="Copy {0} to {1}">
            <behaviors:MultiBindingItem 
                    Value="{Binding SelectedSourceItem}"/>
            <behaviors:MultiBindingItem 
                    Value="{Binding SelectedDestinationItem}"/>
        </behaviors:MultiBindingBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Since there's no `IMultiValueConverter` in UWP, Cimbalino provides `MultiValueConverterBase` as an alternative with a very similar signature.

For more details you can check the [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Cimbalino/Cimbalino-Toolkit/tree/master/samples/MultiBinding) or [my blogpost on the subject](http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20160221-MultibindingInUniversalWindowsApps.html).

Comment: Yes i saw about this in some posts. This works pretty good. Only one concern: I read somewhere that this throws exception in release mode. Are you aware of this or you never came across such issue? Also this is very strange that UWP don't have a easy way for multi-binding which used to be in WPF!

Comment: @pratik I don't think I've ever tested in release mode. It shouldn't be too difficult to try it out, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to the collection item itself rather than discrete properties of it and then use a converter to extract and return a value based on the values of the collection item you're interested in. Basically just make the converters smarter.

This won't work for two way bindings, but then again, neither does MultiBinding.

Comment: Thanks! this helps in binding. But the INotifyPropertyChanged don't work here. I guess as we are not explicitly mentioning the binding variable in this case right? Mentioning nothing in binding sends the entire item. Any work around for this?